# Вывести объект со свойствами, которые совпадают с ключами массива

Tags: javascript, объекты

Должен получить на выходе следующее:

```
console.log(pickProps({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, ['a', 'c'])); // ==> { a: 1, c: 3 }
console.log(pickProps({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, ['a', 'c', 'd', 'hex'])); // ==> { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Мне нужно в задачке использовать для перебора свойств объекта цикл for..in. Можно как-то одной строкой сравнить свойства объекта и ключи массива чтобы получить нужный объект?

```
const pickProps = (obj, props) => {

let resultObj = {};

    for (let key in obj) {

          resultObj = .....
    }

    return resultObj;
};
```

Comment: А что вы пробовали сделать?

Comment: `for..in` тут вообще не нужен.

Comment: мне надо не использовать методы класса Object - keys(), values(), entries()

Comment: @Ector, эти методы тут тем более не нужны

Comment: как тогда реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае задача сводится к свертке массива. Это реализуется при использовании метода [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
props.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
    if (cur in obj) { // если поле есть в объекте
        acc[cur] = obj[cur]; // записываем в результат
    }
    return acc;
},
{}) // начальное значение пустой массив
```

Точно так же можно реализовать с помощью обычного цикла

```js
const pickProps = (obj, props) => {

  let resultObj = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    const cur = props[i];
    if (cur in obj) {
      resultObj[cur] = obj[cur]
    }
  }

  return resultObj;
};

console.log(pickProps({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}, ['a', 'c'])); // ==> { a: 1, c: 3 }
console.log(pickProps({
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}, ['a', 'c', 'd', 'hex'])); // ==> { a: 1, c: 3 }
```